# woocommerce "mysite/cart/" redirects to "mysite/cart/" again to a blank instead of "mysite/checkout/"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I am trying to trouble shoot my woo commerce this is what I experience.

woocommerce "mysite/cart/"page when I click "proceed to checkout" redirects to "mysite/cart/" again to a blank page instead of "mysite/checkout/"

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dashboard go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Checkout tab -> Checkout pages section and the second dropdown list is for what page the checkout is at. Change that option to the page called Checkout and save the changes.